# Break a parent divs padding

Tags: css

So say I have a wrapper div with 20px padding and I have a div with width 100% and border-top 1px in order to make a divider line. BUT I want this line to touch the edges of the wrapper div. how can I do this without absolute positioning?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't change the padding of the parent div?

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of:

```
margin-top: -1px;
```

or

```
position: relative;
top: -1px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#parent {
    padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}

#child {
   border-top: solid 1px #f00;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 20px;
}
```

This way you will still have 20px padding from each side, and the border of the child element will be touching the parent element. Hope this is what you wanted, you should be a little more specific when you ask questions, providing some of your code, or at least an image of what you want to accomplish.